# How to modify the properties of .NET 8 identity bearer token

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, .net-8.0

I want to use the .NET 8 identity feature in my project but I want a way to review and possibly modify some of the properties like expiration time of the token and the refresh token, the issuer, the audience and also the associated claims properties embedded in it.

Please how can I go about this?

Thank you

Comment: The bearerToken handler don't have any interesting event handler that allows you to modify the issued tokens (just checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.bearertoken.bearertokenevents ) so, I guess the you need to look at the service issuing the signing to the BearerToken handler. I also did blog about the handler here https://nestenius.se/2023/08/29/bearertoken-the-new-authentication-handler-in-net-8/

Comment: Thank you @ToreNestenius for your contribution. I am actually not looking for a way to modify the properties after they are already in the token. I am looking for a way to add more to it at the point of generating the token so that mine can contain my custom values as I desire such as the expiration time to be 5 minutes instead of the default value and I can add other properties before issuing the token. If there is a way to do that, I'll be delighted to see it.

Comment: @jeb I am not talking about JWT token. .NET 8 comes with a custom token which is not a JWT token. That is what I am trying to find a way to modify the default properties it comes with. Thank you for asking. You can check the internet about .NET 8 identity to understand more

Comment: Looking at the source code here, I don't see any extensibility point we could use to customize the response message. The `AccessTokenResponse` type is harcoded inside the `HandleSignInAsync` method with no way of extending it. 
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b3b8dffff4d092058b2d8942268b498cbfdb14ec/src/Security/Authentication/BearerToken/src/BearerTokenHandler.cs#L71